# How to interpret character ranges in charmap files?

Tags: locale, posix, character-encoding

The charmap file `/usr/share/i18n/charmaps/UTF-8.gz` has this line:

```
<U3400>..<U343F> /xe3/x90/x80 <CJK Ideograph Extension A>
```

The map page for `charmap(5)` only says that it means a range. Then I found [the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap06.html#tag_06_04), but it says that the number in the character name is supposed to be in decimal, not hex, and it uses 3 dots as opposed to 2 in the man page. So, how should I interpret character ranges in charmap files? Especially if I see something like

```
<U3400>..<U3430> /xe3/x90/x80 <CJK Ideograph Extension A>
```

then is the range in decimal or hex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

glibc allows three-dot decimal ranges (as in POSIX) and two-dot hexadecimal ranges. This doesn't appear to be documented anywhere, but we can see it in the source code. This is **not** defined portable behaviour, but an extension of glibc and possibly others. If you're writing your own files, use decimal.

---

Let's confirm that this is the actual behaviour of glibc.

[When processing a range, glibc uses](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=locale/programs/charmap.c;h=129aefffc1dbda284ebfe6da08e9243ce4c38073;hb=HEAD#l998):

```
   if (decimal_ellipsis)
     while (isdigit (*cp) && cp >= from)
       --cp;
   else
     while (isxdigit (*cp) && cp >= from)
       {
         if (!isdigit (*cp) && !isupper (*cp))
           lr_error (lr, _("\
 hexadecimal range format should use only capital characters"));
         --cp;
       }
```

where `isxdigit` validates a hex digit, and `isdigit` decimal. Later, it branches the conversion to integer of the consumed substring in the same way and carries on as you'd expect. [Earlier, it has determined the kind of ellipsis in question during parsing](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=locale/programs/charmap.c;h=129aefffc1dbda284ebfe6da08e9243ce4c38073;hb=HEAD#l529), obtained [from the lexer](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=locale/programs/linereader.c;h=52b340963aa27792c1b0b30786ade7970faf9ca1;hb=HEAD#l241).

The UTF-8 charmap file [is mechanically generated](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=localedata/unicode-gen/utf8_gen.py;h=ab03e750a663876811c1b1cb9866e6837135e05b;hb=HEAD#l78) from unicode.org's `UnicodeData.txt`, creating 64-codepoint ranges with two dots. I suppose that this convenient auto-generation is at least partially behind the extension, but I don't know. Earlier versions of glibc also generated it, but using a different program and the same format.

Again, this doesn't appear to be documented anywhere, and since it's auto-generated right next to where it's used it conceivably could change, but I imagine it will be stable.

---

If given something like

```
<U3400>..<U3430> /xe3/x90/x80 <CJK Ideograph Extension A>
```

then it is a **hexadecimal** range, because it uses two dots. With three dots, it would be a POSIX decimal range.

If you're on another system that doesn't have this extension, it would just be a syntax error. A portable character map file should only use the decimal ranges.

Answer (score -1):

The part in angular brackets (`<U3400>`) is the [UCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Coded_Character_Set) name of the character, and the digits are in **hexadecimal**, as you can see when comparing the symbolic name `<ESC>` and its UCS equivalent `<U001B>` in the spec you linked.

The next part is the encoding. As you can see from the spec, it has 3 forms:

> `\d123` where *123* is decimal,
>   `\x123` where *123* is hexadecimal, and
>   `\123` where *123* is octal.

So `<U3400>` is represented by the hexadecimal byte sequence `e3 90 80`, `<U3401>` is represented by the hexadecimal byte sequence `e3 90 81`, and so on.

If you compare that with the description of the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding, you see that it matches: The 3-byte sequence as bits is

```
11100011  10010000  10000000
```

and if you compare that with

```
1110xxxx  10yyyyyy  10zzzzzz
```

you see that the encoded number is `xxxx yyyy yyzz zzzz`, or `0011 0100 0000 000`, or `3400` in hex.

Comment: `...` is most definitely _not_ a typo, but (like most other GNU projects) glibc has non-portable extensions to the standard